# Thousands of duplicate strings in DevForce taking up memory

Tags: c#, memory, devforce

After doing memory profiling recently with dotMemory, we discovered that there were over a hundred thousand duplicate strings in memory amounting to over 40 MB. As a data-heavy app we are looking to pare down everywhere we can.

Looking at the profile, almost all of it comes from the getter on EntityRelationLink.UniqueName. It has to concatenate strings, so the string doesn't get interned by default, even though as a unique name I'd imagine it doesn't change very much. Is there any way to force interning on this string?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably nothing you can do from the application side to modify this behavior.

The issue might be more apparent with large models when doing a lot of 1) entity graph imports, 2) work with the EntityCacheState, or 3) querying of entity graphs.  Although you are seeing a significant number of duplicate strings, the good news is that they should be available for garbage collection.

We can look at addressing this behavior, although I don't know that interning is the answer in this case.  When the EntityServer is hosted by IIS we'd want to avoid having interned strings outlive the EntityServer.  Model metadata, such as the EntityRelationLink, is generally immutable after it's loaded, so there should be some optimizations we can make in the UniqueName getter to avoid the repetitive string concatenation it's doing.

Which version of DevForce are you using?

Comment: For us the strings don't go away.  It looks like the `EntityReferenceManager` use the `UniqueName` as the key in it's `Map` dictionary.  We have many entities that live for the whole lifetime of the application (or app is very data-driven) so these Maps stay around forever and so all the UniqueNames.  We may have 1,000 of one entity so that same string is in memory 1,000 times.

Comment: I can understand the aversion to string interning - especially in an environment like IIS.  I think many of our problems would be solved if the UniqueName property was just eagerly calculated when the `EntityRelationLink` is constructed (instead of a new instance being created on each `get`).  Then at least there is just the one instance of the string that ends up getting used as the key in all the `EntityReferenceManager` dictionaries.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  We should be able to format the UniqueName during construction and then use that in the getter; this should solve the problem with duplicates.

Comment: Also, we are on version 7.2.5.  The upgrade to 7.3.0 has so far scared us enough that we've stayed on 7.2.5 (because of the move to the BCL Async package - which I know is the right decision but is still scary for us).  But maybe this fix could be enough convince us to upgrade :-)

Comment: We've upgraded to 7.4.0 and it looks like this issue has been fixed.  Thanks!